# Apache Ranger REST API addUsersAndGroups returns 404 not found

Tags: apache-ranger

We have installed Apache Ranger and the Web UI works fine, most of the REST API method works fine on both PublicAPIsv2 and RoleREST as per https://ranger.apache.org/apidocs/ui/index.html.
I can get “test_role” id by calling `GET /public/v2/api/roles/name/test_role` which returns the id 409.
I can get test_role content by calling `GET /public/v2/api/roles/409`
I can change test_role users list by editing the response I get from `GET /public/v2/api/roles/409`  and submitting it through `PUT /public/v2/api/roles/409`

The body is:

```
{
    "id": 409,
    "isEnabled": true,
    "createdBy": "admin",
    "updatedBy": "admin",
    "createTime": 1598241102841,
    "updateTime": 1601975068428,
    "name": "test_role",
    "options": {},
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "test_user1”,
            "isAdmin": true
        },
        {
            "name": “test_user2”,
            "isAdmin": true
        },
        {
            "name": “test_user3”,
            "isAdmin": false
        }
    ],
    "groups": [
        {
            "name": "test_group”,
            "isAdmin": false
        }
    ],
    "roles": []
}
```

But calling `PUT /public/v2/api/roles/409/addUsersAndGroups` returns “404 not found”.
I tried with the same body as above as parameter, and also with:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "name": “test_user4”,
            "isAdmin": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Would anybody know what is the correct body to send as parameter to:
`/public/v2/api/roles/409/addUsersAndGroups`?
Also, making a wrong call such as `GET /public/v2/api/roles/409/addUsersAndGroups` returns “405 method not allowed”. So I believe it shows the end point does exist.   I’m not sure why calling `PUT public/v2/api/roles/409/addUsersAndGroups` with (probably) incorrect body returns “404 not found” and not an error message related to the wrong parameter.

Comment: no solution yet... however workaround works.

Comment: Same problem, the point is that if you use `https://ranger_url/service/roles/roles/<id>` you would replace ENTIRELY the role. It's quite different from what you want to achieve, which is adding A user to a role.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because Apache Ranger API documentation is wrong, remove the suffix /addUsersAndGroups of your endpoint and it will work.

Example: `https://ranger_url/service/roles/roles/409`

Where 409 is the role ID, as you're using on your example.

The body that is needed:

```
{
    "name": "test_role",
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "test_user1",
            "isAdmin": true
        }
    ]
}
```